# Magento 2.3 - To add the google captcha in cash on delivery payment method on payment step before place order button

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, cash-on-delivery, place-order, recaptcha

I need to show google captcha on particular cash on delivery payment method on payment step before placing an order as a part of manual verification of humans.

For checkout i'm using Magento standard checkout process not any third party extensions onestepcheckout.